# BDSF-material changes size

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a simple procedural BDSF-material: WaveTexture + ColorRamp.

But if I use the same material on different objects the **texture gets resized**.
Small objects get a finer structure. Bigger ones are coarser.

Scaling of the objects is applied (=1).

What am I missing?

[image: First Try]

@moonboots: Just Wavetexture as seen in Pic 1.

@L0Lock
My german version doesn't use the same words, but best I could find is seen on picture 2. Still the same problem.
[image: Second try, according to L0Lock]

Comment: what output of the Texture Coordinate node are you using?

Comment: Just Wavetexture as seen in Pic 1.

Comment: Generated will squeaze the texture according to the object proportion, it may be the problem here, try the Object output, or please share your file

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have access to Blender right now, will post screenshots later)

From your screenshot, it looks like you have not specified any mapping nor texture coordinate to your textures, so they use the default one which is UV mapping.

So the simple answer would be that your UV mapping isn't adapted to your needs and you should probably redo it.

OR, if you don't care about UVs and just want to have your texture evenly mapped everywhere, so let's do <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > `Vector` > `Texture Coordinates` node, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Vector > Mapping node. Plug the `Generated` texture coordinate into the `Mapping` node, and the `Mapping` node to your textures' Vector inputs.
You can control the location, rotation and scale of your textures via the mapping node.

Comment: I answered by updating my question, as I cant upload pics in comment.

Comment: Yes, I don't care about UVs. I just want the same wood structure, regardless to object size.

Comment: Texture/generated -> Mapping/Scale gives a plane light brown face. Dividing/Multiplying don't help.

Comment: I see in your new screenshot that you actually have different objects, that can change things a bit :o Try the Object texture coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

**Thx for your Help!**

This did the Job:

> ⇧ ShiftA > Vector > Texture Coordinates node, then ⇧ ShiftA > Vector > Mapping node. Plug the *Generated texture* coordinate into the Mapping node, and the Mapping node to your textures' Vector inputs.

> try the Object output,

Instead of *Generated texture* I had to use **Object** -> Vector.
Additional mapping is not required.

[image: Solution]

Now I understand: UV-mapping takes target object as 'unit', and has to be resized according the size of object.